# Android list adapter - only giving one value

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I have a listview adapter that takes data from an array and should put them into a listview. However, the listview will only show one item from the array - and show it in all the rows of the listview. Heres my code, does anything look wrong?

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, MainActivity.values) {
              @Override
              public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
                View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
                TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

                int i = 0;
                int p = 0;

                text1.setText(MainActivity.values[i]);
                text2.setText(MainActivity.numvalues[i]);
                i++;

                return view;
              }
            };
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
```

Comment: use position instead of i

Answer (score 5, accepted):

try replacing these lines

```
int i = 0;
int p = 0;
text1.setText(MainActivity.values[i]);
text2.setText(MainActivity.numvalues[i]);
i++;
```

with

```
text1.setText(MainActivity.values[position]);
text2.setText(MainActivity.numvalues[position]);
```

In your code every time the value of i gets initialized to 0, that is why you will see only that row repeated in your listview

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `position` to get value from array instead of `i` which set 0 for each item :

```
text1.setText(MainActivity.values[position]);
text2.setText(MainActivity.numvalues[position]);
```

Answer (score 3):

You are doing it wrong. In `getView` method you are initialising the i every time

```
            int i = 0;
            int p = 0;

            text1.setText(MainActivity.values[i]);
            text2.setText(MainActivity.numvalues[i]);
            i++;
```

Change your code as below

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(getApplicationContext(), android.R.layout.simple_list_item_2, android.R.id.text1, MainActivity.values) {
          @Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView text1 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            TextView text2 = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text2);

            text1.setText(MainActivity.values[position]);
            text2.setText(MainActivity.numvalues[position]);

            return view;
          }
        };
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```